# Download pdf from base64 url webview swift

Tags: swift, webkit

I am trying to download a pdf from a url in a webview to the device. here is what the base64 endpoint looks like `data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJf////8KOCAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRXh0R1N0YXRlCi9jYSAxCj4+CmVuZG9iagoxMiAwIG9iago8 ... JSVFT0YK`

Problem now is getting the data and downloading to show Activity view controller

```
private func downloadData(from url: URL, fileName: String, completion: @escaping (Bool, URL?) -> Void) {
        webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies() { cookies in
            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookies(cookies, for: url, mainDocumentURL: nil)
            let task = session.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in
                if let localURL = localURL {

                    let destinationURL = self.moveDownloadedFile(url: localURL, fileName: fileName)
                    completion(true, destinationURL)
                }
                else {
                    completion(false, nil)
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

in the navigationResponse I have this but the my break point is not triggered.

```
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: url.absoluteString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                        print("THE MINETYPE data: \(data)")
                    }
```

Comment: You need to remove the part `data:application/pdf;base64,`...  But the "////" seems strange...

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't rememberd that `/` was valid in Base64, because I them as 4 consecutive, but they are allowed.

Comment: Removing data:application/pdf;base64, was enough. Thanks